# Wait for the SDK load event: not working?

Tags: javascript, facebook, sdk, facebook-messenger-bot, messenger

Trying to update the Messenger customer chat greeting message upon loading.

Following SDK documentation, I should used the window.extAsyncInit() to include the function to update the message. Like this:

```js
window.extAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.CustomerChat.update({  
      logged_in_greeting: "my greeting message",
      logged_out_greeting: "my greeting message",
    });
};
```

However it doesn't work. The only way is by setting a delay, but that of course is not ideal.

Any idea how to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which SDK documentation are we talking about here? `extAsyncInit` is for the Messenger Extensions SDK, but the Customer Chat SDK is compatible with the “standard” JS SDK, and that uses `fbAsyncInit`, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart/#loading

Comment: Right, my confusion. However it doesn't seem to be working anyway.

Comment: Can you show how you are embedding the SDK?

Comment: I have been using manychat, I've also tried their mcAsyncInit method, but no way.